# Filter an Array of Values and group them

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I have an array that i need to sort and put values that are too similar together in another array.

e.g

```
function group (arrData) {
   for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
     if (
         (array[i + 1] - array[i]
        ) < 5) {
           return array[i];
     }
   }
 }

const arr = [1,15,16,33,35,37,55,58]
const newArr = arr.map((item,index,array) => group(array));
```

but it returns only one value. How do i fix this?

as for desired output : [[15,16],[33,35,36],[55,58]]

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: are the values always sorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could sort the array, if not in ascending order and then reduce this array by checking the actual value and the predecessor.

If the dela is greater or equal `5` or if youi got the first value of the array, then push an empty array to the result set.

Then push the value to the last array in the result set.

```js
var array = [1, 15, 16, 33, 35, 37, 55, 58],
    result = array
        .sort((a, b) => a - b)                       // not necessary with sorted data
        .reduce((r, v, i, a) => {
            if (!i || v - a[i - 1] >= 5) r.push([]);
            r[r.length - 1].push(v);
            return r;
        }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The `sort` _callback function_ is not necessary as it's the default behavior

Comment: @Avraham, no it does not work without a callback, because the built in default callback sorts by the string representation of the values. that means, `100` is sorted after `1` and before `16` for example.

Comment: Why `>=5`, Code fails for this input `array = [1, 15, 16, 30, 39, 40, 55, 58]`

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr, what is actually failing? you could change the comparison value, if needed.

Comment: nothing is failing, even with arrays that contain objects

Comment: Input `[1, 15, 16, 30, 39, 40, 55, 58]` as `[ [ 1 ], [ 15, 16 ], [ 30 ], [ 39, 40 ], [ 55, 58 ] ]` . It should be `[ [ 1 ], [ 15, 16 ], [ 30, 39 ], [ 40 ], [ 55, 58 ] ]` ? Am I right ?

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr, no. the question has a delta of less than 5 as condition for the same group. you take a group with `Math.floor(value / 10)`. that is a different question.